# getchangedcells returns empty array

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

After changing the value of a cell, I call `getchangedcells` but the array returned is always empty. this is my jqgrid (I'm using struts2-jquery plugin):

```
<sjg:grid id="tableau" 
      cellEdit="true"
      cellurl="%{editRequetesUrl}"
      dataType="json" href="%{listeRequetesUrl}"  
      gridModel="requetesRoutage"
      multiselect="true"
      width="940" onCompleteTopics="complete" rowNum="-1"
      >
    <sjg:gridColumn formatter="modifyRequeteFormatter"
        width="20" name="act2" index="act2" title="" align="center"
        sortable="false"/>

    <sjg:gridColumn title="" formatter="deleteFormatter"
                name="act" index="act" width="20" sortable="false"
                align="center" />

    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id"
                title="" hidden="true" sortable="false" />

    <sjg:gridColumn name="requete.nomRequete" index="type"
                title="%{getText('label.abonnement.type1')}"
                sortable="true" />

    <sjg:gridColumn name="codeEdition.libelle" index="codeEdition"
                title="%{getText('label.abonnement.codeEdition')}"
                editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="true" />

    <sjg:gridColumn name="nombreExemplaire" index="nombreExemplaire"
                title="%{getText('label.routage.nbExemplaires')}"
                editable="true" edittype="text" formatter="integer"
                sortable="true" />

</sjg:grid>
```

When debugging I found that the cell got the class `dirty-cell`, and the row got `edited`

Comment: One can't see any usage of `getChangedCells` in the code which you posted. Moreover are you sure that you use correct case of the name of the function (you wrote `getchangedcells` instead of `getChangedCells`). Which value of parameter of `getChangedCells` you used? If you want get edited cells you should use `'dirty'` as the option of `getChangedCells`.